# Extract string inside <> in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, regular-language

I have a string looking like this:

```
$string = "Testing example < India > Rahul pune< Canada >";//String
preg_match("/\<(.*?)\>/", $string, $matches);//extracting string inside<>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => < India > [1] => India )
```

Result: Array ( [0] =>India [1] => Canada )
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Look at the difference between `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`.

Comment: @Shrenik if answers helpful for you accept/upvote for that

Comment: @Rakesh: Thanks for help. While vote up it is giving me an error "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". I will accept as an right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code if you want to remove the leading and trailing spaces in  the strings which are present inside `<>` ,

```
<?php
$string = "Testing example < India > Rahul pune< Canada >";
preg_match_all("/<\s*(.*?)\s*>/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) if you want to get all the matches:

```
preg_match_all("/\<(.*?)>/", $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$string = "Testing example < India > Rahul pune< Canada >";//String
preg_match_all("/<(.*?)\>/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<([^<>]*)>
```

Try this.This will work.